# rpi3b+ not showing on local network devices list

Tags: networking, ssh, pi-3b+

## Problem

Cannot ssh into Pi connected within local network.

### Details

Raspberry Pi 3B+ with fresh install of Raspbian Buster. (freshly installed as an attempt to fix said problem)

- Connected and associated with local Wi-Fi network (while connected to display).
- IP address is assigned and can be shown using the `ifconfig` command.
- SSH server is turned on through `raspi-config` menu, can ssh into itself.

---

- Cannot discover Pi using Advanced IP Scanner or Fing. (Same network)
- Can discover Pi through router settings page. IP address is correctly assigned to said Pi in DHCP settings.
- Connecting to Pi using puTTY through ssh connection times out. (Windows)
- Connection to Pi using ConnectBot through ssh connection fails. (Android)

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you disabled "device isolation" in your home router's config pages?

Comment: I don't see a setting like that in the router settings. If it helps, Advanced IP scanner and Fing does return the rest of the connected devices, such as mobile phones and laptops.

Comment: try a wired connection, if that works, then the issue may well be "device isolation" in the wifi settings of your home router

Comment: update: a wired connection does work (device is scannable and connectable), but there is no "device isolation" setting in the router.